# How to check if the current page is a "personal activity"-page in buddypress?

Tags: buddypress, conditional-tags

I want to modify some general text in my personal-activity page in buddypress.
Does any one know any conditional tag like `is_page('activity')` things are there for checking this?
the page can be navigated as

> member profile page -> activity tab

Thanks in advance :)
Vignesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the conditionals in docs :)
they are like as follow,

```
bp_is_user_profile() /* will check the current page as personal profile */
bp_is_user_activity() /* will check the current page as personal activity */
```